# How to prevent the click event in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

There is one toggle switch, When click on a toggle it switches ON and popup with close and Ok button appears.
But if I again click on a toggle then it switches off and toggle disappears.
The actual requirement is, with a every click for which the toggle switches ON and popup appears, the toggle switch should not get switch OFF until user click on close button which is present in popup.

http://jsfiddle.net/5rdbe08a/3/

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var status = 0;
            $(document).on('click', '#isImpliedDelete', function () {
                status++;
                console.log(status);
                var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
                popup.classList.toggle("show");
                if (status % 2 == 0) {
                    $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', false);

                } else {
                    $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', true);
                }
            });

            $("#isImpliedDelete").click(function () {
                $("#myPopup").show();
                if ($("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', false) == true) {
                    $("#myPopup").show();
                }
            });

            $("#ok").on('click', function () {
                $("#myPopup").hide()
                $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', false);
            });

            $("#close").on('click', function () {
                if ($("#myPopup").show() == true) {
                    $("#myPopup").hide();
                }
                $("#isImpliedDelete").click();
                $("#submitBtn").prop('disabled', false);
                console.log("close");

            });
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of logic, what you want to do is check first if the modal is visible or not. If it isn't, then the switch should launch the modal. If it's visible, then the switch should remain in it's current state (we'll use `e.preventDefault();` to do this).

Here is a modified version of your fiddle:
EDIT2: updated fiddle based on new comment:

http://jsfiddle.net/5fb4xc0L/1/

*One observation about your code:*
I see that you are using the jquery [hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) function BUT you are also using separate "show" and "hide" classes to visually toggle the visibility  of the modal. You cannot use `hide()` to hide the element then expect that toggling the class `.show` to bring it back. [Here is an explanation](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone/)

Comment: Thanks Code is working fine but the only thing is when clicked on OK button in a popup, the toggle switch should be ON and when click on Close button the toggle switch should be OFF.
But in this case for both the case, toggle switch gets OFF only.

Comment: Also, once toggle switch become ON after clicking on ok button in popup and then after if user want to OFF the toggle switch then popup should not appear.
In simple word, if toggle is in OFF state and someone trying to ON it then popup should appear and if toggle is in ON state and someone trying to OFF it then popup should not appear

Comment: i've updated the fiddle to add this logic, along with some notes in the "OK on click" event. Not sure what the behavior should be for the "submit" button though

Comment: 1.Initially toggle is in OFF state and (#submitBtn) is enable.
2.When user click on toggle(to make it ON) , popup should appear , #submitBtn should be disabled and user should not make the toggle switch OFF until  clicks close button in popup.
3.Suppose user click on close button then toggle switch should be OFF and #submitBtn should be enable (with this we are at initial stage and step 1,2,3 should be repeated )

Comment: 4. Suppose user click on OK button then toggle switch should be ON and #submitBtn should be enable.
5. Now at step 4, if user want to to OFF the toggle switch then it should get OFF without appearing any popup and #submitBtn should be enable.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed use case. I've updated the fiddle. So in addition to checking the visibility of the modal, we'll also check if the toggle is on/off. We'll use these two to determine the correct form action. I used a detailed IF/THEN block to show you this logic. Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you actually want but i just solve your toggle problem. have a look

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click','#isImpliedDelete',function(){
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    $('#myPopup').addClass('show');
  })
  
  $(document).on('click','#ok',function(){
      $(this).parents('.popup').next('.input-group-prepend').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
      $('#myPopup').removeClass('show');
      $('#isImpliedDelete').removeAttr('disabled')
  })

})
```

```css
/* Radio Switches */
        .switch {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 60px;
            height: 34px;
        }

        .switch input {
            opacity: 0;
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
        }

        .slider {
            position: absolute;
            cursor: pointer;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            background-color: #3c3c3c;
            -webkit-transition: .4s;
            transition: .4s;
        }

        .slider:before {
            position: absolute;
            content: "";
            height: 26px;
            width: 26px;
            left: 4px;
            bottom: 4px;
            background-color: white;
            -webkit-transition: .4s;
            transition: .4s;
        }

        input:checked+.slider {
            background-color: #00afaa;
        }

        input:focus+.slider {
            box-shadow: 0 0 1px #00afaa;
        }

        input:checked+.slider:before {
            -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
            -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
            transform: translateX(26px);
        }

        /* Rounded sliders */
        .slider.round {
            border-radius: 34px;
        }

        .slider.round:before {
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

        /* Popup container - can be anything you want */
        .popup {

            position: relative;
            align-content: center;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;

            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 0 auto;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
        }


        /* The actual popup */
        .popup .popuptext {


            align-content: center;

            visibility: hidden;
            width: 396px;
            border-style: groove;

            background-color: #555;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 6px;
            padding: 5px 0;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 10000;
            /* bottom: 25%; */
            top: -50px;
            left: 310px;
            /* margin-left: -180px; */


        }

        /* Popup arrow */
        .popup .popuptext::after {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 100%;
            /* left: 50%; */
            margin-left: -80px;
            border-width: 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
        }

        /* Toggle this class - hide and show the popup visible */
        .popup .show {
            visibility: visible;
            -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
            animation: fadeIn 1s;
        }

        .popup .hide {
            visibility: hidden;
            -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
            animation: fadeIn 1s;
        }

        /* Add animation (fade in the popup) */
        @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            to {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        @keyframes fadeIn {
            from {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            to {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br> <br> <br>


    <div class="popup">
        <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Hello,How are you?
            <button id="ok">Ok</button>
            <button id="close">Close</button>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label class="switch">
            <input id="isImpliedDelete" name="isImpliedDelete" type="checkbox">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
        </label>
    </div>

    <br> <br> <br>

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="submitBtn" >
        <i class="fa fa-file-upload mr-2"></i> Button
    </button>
```

Comment down if you want something different from it.

Answer (score 0):

Used e.preventDefault() in click function.

`$('#<id>').on(click,function(e){ e.preventDefault(); //Do your task });`